# Why <? extends Number> not working for Integer?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Why

```
Predicate<? super Integer> isGreaterThanZero = num -> num.intValue() > 0;
```

works for

```
isGreaterThanZero.test( new Integer( 2 ));
```

and not

```
Predicate<? extends Number> isGreaterThanZero = num -> num.intValue() > 0;
```

I see them as the same since `Integer` **is-a** `Number`

Comment: Don't use `new Integer()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you declare `Predicate<? extends Number> isGreaterThanZero`, you are telling the compiler that `isGreaterThanZero` is a `Predicate` parametrized by some unknown subtype of `Number`.

As far as the compiler knows, it could be a `Predicate<Double>` or a `Predicate<BigInteger>`.  Can you safely pass an `Integer` to `test(Double x)` or to `test(BigInteger x)`?  You cannot.  The only thing that you can safely pass to `test` method of `Predicate<? extends Number>` is `null`.

If you want `isGreaterThanZero` to be a predicate that works on any subtype of `Number`, you should declare it as `Predicate<Number>`.

Comment: so it works for `super` since the Integer is found in the root of my generics?

Comment: if Number has only Integer as its subclass, will it work? Will java infer(if that's the right term) that Number has only one possible subclass?

Comment: It works for `super` because `Integer` is subtype of any class that satisfies wildcard `? super Number`.  So whatever class the wildcard happens to represent, `Predicate<? super Number>` can *consume* an `Integer`.  You may want to read through http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/3920048 for an in-depth explanation of these issues and the *PECS* mnemonic.

Comment: @fireflieslive For your second question, no, compiler wouldn't have let you do this if there were only one subtype of `Number`.  What if you compile your code and tomorrow write a new subtype of `Number`?  Now your compiled code is not type-safe.

Comment: @fireflieslive: even if you have a `Predicate<? extends Integer>` (note that `Integer` is `final`), you can’t pass an `Integer` to its `test` method. There is no guaranty that `Integer` will still be `final` and without subclasses at runtime.